# Ping server remotely timed out

Tags: ping, hostname, host

I recently setup local Ubuntu server to host VS Code and NGINX servers which work fine on codeserver (hostname) and can ping the hostname and IP address remotely. The problem I am facing is that I cannot ping new host created such as project.codeserver or codeserver/project remotely but can ping them while on the server.

In etc/hosts I have typed this 192.168.1.235 codeserver project.codeserver. I also turn off the UFW and same result appear so I think it something else that preventing me to ping the secondary host name.

Any chance someone point me the direction to how can I ping the secondary host remotely?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a virtual machine, you should check the hypervisor's NIC configuration. There may be a problem with his gateway. I recommend that you review the IP configuration on the server you are having problems with.

In general, with the Netmask definition, the Gateway definition is made incorrectly, which can cause icmq_request_timeout of the device. Of course, I definitely cannot say that the problem is caused by this. More information is needed for this. Can you try to reach your machine with the `traceroute` command? With this output, you can see at what stage the timeout is. (Is it NIC interface, Server configuration etc.)